# how to implement infinite scroll pagination in angular 5?

Tags: mongodb, angular5

I need to implement  infinite scroll pagination in angular 5. I have try infinite scroll but its not working properly. i need to show first 10 post with their comments, after scroll that 10 comment need to call service (10 post) again and append the data with existing posts.

Comment: Welcome to stak overflow! What have you tried ? Give some code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **ngx-infinite-scroll**.

```
npm install ngx-infinite-scroll --save
```

See demo [**plnkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/DrEDetYnZkFxR7OWWrxS?p=preview).

In your component template:

```
<div class="search-results"
     data-infinite-scroll
     debounce
     [infiniteScrollDistance]="scrollDistance"
     [infiniteScrollUpDistance]="scrollUpDistance"
     [infiniteScrollThrottle]="throttle"
     (scrolled)="onScrollDown()"
     (scrolledUp)="onUp()">
  <p *ngFor="let i of array">
    {{ i }}
  </p>
</div>
```

In your component controller:

```
 onScrollDown (ev) {
    console.log('scrolled down!!', ev);

    // add another 10 items
    const start = this.sum;
    this.sum += 10;
    this.appendItems(start, this.sum);

    this.direction = 'down'
  }

  onUp(ev) {
    console.log('scrolled up!', ev);
    const start = this.sum;
    this.sum += 10;
    this.prependItems(start, this.sum);

    this.direction = 'up';
  }
```

This is done with a simple data service, but you can implement a custom method retrieving data from database. For example:

```
// Page 1
db.comments.find().limit(10)

// Page 2
db.comments.find().skip(10).limit(10)

// Page 3
db.comments.find().skip(10).limit(10)
```

Comment: I have try this but its not work . it calls service after each scroll and i need to call service after scrolling 10 posts .

Comment: how to push service call (data-object) into exiting object. i have tried to push but my web app get freeze.. not working...!